# Magento PayPal Payment Pro not sending confirmation email

Tags: php, email, magento, paypal, payment

I have an issue with PayPal Payment Pro not sending confirmation email after credit card has been authorized. PayPal Express Checkout works just fine.

I don't see an option to change this. Can anyone point me to the right direction to which file I should edit to get PayPal Payment Pro to send out an order confirmation email after the payment is authorized?

(Changing `authorize` to `sale` won't work for me.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**PayPal Payment Pro** not send confirmation email facility.
 But you can achieve it by creating observer after payment receive.

- You may use event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`. This
  can be used if your order success.
- There is another event `sales_order_payment_pay`. This
  can be used if your order success. It may also use
  in your case.

1 ) Make custom config.xml for call observer file

The config.xml defines your module and declares your event listener for a given event (`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` is sent when onepage checkout process is complete, `sales_order_payment_pay` is sent when the payment has been confirmed).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>            
            <sales_order_payment_pay>
                <observers>
                    <Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customFunction</method>
                    </Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_pay>
        </events>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

2 ) create observer.php file inside your module/Model directory and paste this code

```
<?php
  class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

         $order_id = $observer->getData('order_ids');
         $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
         //your code here


    }        

}
```

Tell me if further help needs

Answer (score 0):

PayPal will not send the email notification to an authorization payment. Once you capture the amount for this authorization, the email notification will be sent to you.
If you want to get the notification for an incoming authorization, plz use Instant Payment Notification(IPN). Please check the settings in Magento backend system to get it configured.